# Force login to catalog and product pages in magento 2 custom theme

Tags: magento2, module, catalog, login

I have found this module :

https://github.com/bitExpert/magento2-force-login

But this show errors in Frontend -

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class BitExpert\ForceCustomerLogin\Controller\LoginRouter does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class BitExpert\ForceCustomerLogin\Controller\LoginRouter does not exist
#0 C:\wamp64\www\sk\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('BitExpert\\Force...')
#1 C:\wamp64\www\sk\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('BitExpert\\Force...')
#2 C:\wamp64\www\sk\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('BitExpert\\Force...')
#3 C:\wamp64\www\sk\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('BitExpert\\Force...', Array)
```

Any options to force login in catlog and product page without module

Comment: try to run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile commands** OR get the latest commit of [this](https://github.com/bitExpert/magento2-force-login/releases/tag/v3.0.1) module OR try [this](https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-forcelogin) one?

Comment: please check file permission of file `BitExpert/ForceCustomerLogin/Controller/LoginRoute.php`

Comment: Any options to Force login to catalog and product pages without module

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

It displayed there is syntax error and showed line number. Then updgrade

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

deploy like:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content deploy
```

No in default you cant force login user

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run below commands in order to make it working --

remove cache --

`rm -rf var/cache/* generated/*`

then use upgrade command -

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

then set permission of `var` and `generated` folder -

```
chmod -R 777 var/* generated/*
```

now check, if still issue occurs then you should try compile command --

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: how to force  login particular page url using this link  - https://github.com/mageprince/magento2-forcelogin